# Unable to share dashboard

Tags: azure

I am the owner of the subscription but still don't see any Share buttons. How do I diagnose this?

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. What are you trying to share? Also, this isn't really a programming question and (as written) seems off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let me rephrase. How do I diagnose not being able to share dashboards in a subscription that I own?

Comment: I'm still not understanding: who are you trying to share with? And what exactly is the expected outcome? (and please edit your question; don't post more details in comments).

Comment: I want to promote a dashboard from private to shared so other people on my team can see it. Why does it matter to who? I have absolutely zero ability to share, at all, as I show in my screenshot.

Comment: _Are_ there more people in your team? As in: people you could share the Dashboard to...?

Comment: Try to create a new dashboard or could you see `Shared dashboards` if you search it?

Comment: @rickvdbosch yes

Comment: @JoyWang creating a new dashboard does not fix this. I can see `Shared dashboards` when I click to view all dashboards, but nothing appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing absolutely nothing, my share button came back. Weird!